# What development tool should I use to code in F#?

Tags: visual-studio, f#

I got started with F# back in the day (before VS2010 beta); at the time, if I remember correctly, there was not an Express version of F#, but one could use the VS Shell (I think that was the name) and then install F# on top of it.

What's the current state of affairs? I've read out there that there's no 2010 Express version of F#; is there a 2010 Shell that one can download and install F# latest on top of? If not, what's the best way (if any) to code in F# 2010 for free?

I'm aware that asking for free stuff is A LOT to ask for. But this was possible in VS2008 and I'm wondering if it's also possible in VS2010.

Thanks!

PS - I believe (not sure though) that VS2010 beta can be downloaded for free; the problem with that is that when the final release comes out, one will have to pay for a license. For a guy who codes for fun like myself it doesn't make much sense to buy the full version if I can get the very basic features for free...

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/734525/getting-started-with-f

Basically right now you can use the free VS2008 integrated shell along with the F# CTP, or use the VS2010RC (which is free as a Beta).

(I don't know if there is a VS2010 shell published yet, and I don't know if the F# CTP works with it; for the moment, your best long-term-free strategy is to use 2008.)

Comment: Thanks a lot - One last thing: do you by chance know if it's okay to install VS2008 Shell side by side with C# 2010 Express?

Answer (score 4):

I think you can also use SharpDevelop with F#:

http://www.icsharpcode.net/OpenSource/SD/Features.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you mean visual F# the best tool is Visual Studio 2010 RC:

Check out these links :


[Creating Your First F# Program with Visual Studio](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233160(VS.100).aspx)

[Using Visual F# to Create, Debug, and Deploy an Application](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee241127(VS.100).aspx)


**[Update]**Check out this link too:[Features of the Visual Studio 2010 Release of Visual F#](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd553242%28VS.100%29.aspx)